# Перенаправление codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Привет, я только начал изучать Codeigniter и мне нужно было убрать index.php в строке браузера. Я смог сделать это, создав .htaccess файл и добавив туда

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ index.php/$1   [L]
```

Теперь, например, если я нахожусь на

```
http://academy.kg/country/red
```

Он должен перенаправлять меня на

```
http://academy.kg/country/country
```

Как я понял это тоже работа с .htaccess файлом, но все, что я смог найти это способ удаления index.php со строки браузера. Принцип работы в codeigniter я не знаю. Просьба объяснить все, как можно проще.

Кстати в config у меня стоит:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://academy.kg/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Буду очень признателен и благодарен за помощь. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот документация https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, действительно, можно сделать с помощью .htaccess И Codeigniter тут ни при чём - Вы можете использовать любой фреймворк, но правила работы с .htaccess остануться прежними.

Для перенаправления со страницы page-1 на page-2 следует написать:

```
Redirect 301 /page-1/ http://mysite.ru/page-2/
```

Обратите внимание, что это 301-й редирект (Страница переехала).